# DBeaver keeps giving me popup every time I return to window after editing without saving

Tags: dbeaver

Every time I edit a SQL file in DBeaver and go to a different window and then back to the DBeaver program, I get a popup with title 'File Changed' and description 'The file {file location} has been changed. Replace the editor contents with these changes?'. Is there a way to disable this feature? I just want to be able to edit my file without having to click through these popups every time I go to a different window.

I do not get this popup if I save the file before moving to another window, but it would be preferred if I didn't have to keep saving every time I make a small edit.

[image: popup]

Comment: Hi, if you are using google drive or a similar service to store your dbeaver scripts it could  be related to this issue: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/16952        I continue to have this issue today in both dbeaver community and ultimate.

Comment: This sounds like it is the reason, thanks so much!